# How do you debug unresponsive Django?

Tags: python, django, debugging

I'm learning how to deploy Django site with git.
I have development, staging and production environments. All of them are on my laptop.

OS and servers: Ubuntu 14.04, gunicorn, nginx.

Dev env is in /webapps/mysite-dev/.
Staging env is in /webapps/mysite-staging/.
Production env is in /webapps/mysite-production/.
I also have 3 separate users and directories above are home directories for those users.

In development env my site works absolutely fine. Both with Django's development server and with gunicorn.

From development environment: `git push staging staging`

Post-receive hook makes migrations modifies environment-specific information in files.

Then I start development server `python manage.py runserver`

It starts OK. No errors.

Then I try to load http://127.0.0.1:8000 but the home page of my site does not load and loading is endless.

`top` shows the python process is eating 50% to 80% of CPU.

[image: python process takes around 50% of CPU]

I stop the server with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, but the python process does not go, so I have to kill it. The same happens when using gunicorn.

It looks like an infinite loop, but I have no idea where the bug could be.

I tried putting `pdb.set_trace()` and simple `return HttpResponse("Hello world")` in the first line of my home page view. Nothing. It seems that control of the program just does not get to views at all.

My question: **How do you debug Django when there are no error messages neither in terminal nor in browser?**

Comment: show your urls.py and view which is called on home page.

Comment: urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.home),

Comment: the site works well in my development environment, so I don't think the bug is in urls.py or home page's view.
My question is actually about ways of debugging django when it does not provide any debugging information.
And, yes DEBUG=True in my settings.py

Comment: The site works well in development environment, so you should check gunicon/nginx log file

Comment: this is what I get in nginx-error.log: 2015/07/07 18:17:43 [error] 15965#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 176.76.111.11, server: staging.mysite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/webapps/staging/run/gunicorn.sock/favicon.ico", host: "staging.mysite.com", referrer: "http://staging.mysite.com/"

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. Django was working fine, and suddenly it has gone unresponsive just as you described. Restarting it (including manually killing the python process) and backing out all of my recent changes has done nothing. No indication of any trouble... it just doesn't work.

Comment: Same here, no way to debug.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the development server is not triggered from your browser. Maybe try to bind the django development server to a specific port `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and try to access your site from http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: changing ports does not help